# Concatenate Google Analytics results to ignore country code in URL

Tags: google-analytics

Our website automatically detects a user's region. Though the site structure remains the same across all regions, the content on the page can vary.

As such, URLs are fomatted as so: http://website.com/XX/pagename with XX=country code (e.g. GB, US, IT, etc.)

On Google Analytics, I want to see all of the different country versions of a single page contained as a single result.

For example, if I look at our top pages for January, I see:

```
| URL                     | page views |
|-------------------------|------------|
| website.com/US/page1    | 100        |
| website.com/GB/homepage | 60         |
| website.com/US/homepage | 40         |
| website.com/GB/page1    | 20         |
```

But what I want to see is:

```
| URL                  | page views |
|----------------------|------------|
| website.com/page1    | 120        |
| website.com/homepage | 100        |
```

Wherein the same URL (ignoring country code) is concatenated into one figure.

Is such a thing possible?

My end game here is a desire to see what our most popular pages are across the site in total, regardless of which country the user is browsing from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use an advanced filter in GA so that you take something like `website.com/US/page1` and replace it with `website.com/page1`. This only works on data moving forward from when the filter is applied, and does not change historical data, and cannot be undone once applied. This is another reason why it's always a good idea to have a Raw view which is unfiltered.

For the Advanced Filter, you need to do something like this:

[image]

where it looks for the pattern `/{any two letters}/{anything else}` and outputs just the `/{anything else}` part.